# Ideal order for index creation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table called `timestamppsql`.The column i want to create index on is called `timestamp1` and `id13`.I am gonna test a bounch of queries but most of them look like this:

```
 select date_trunc('day',timestamp1) as day,avg(id13) from timestamppsql where timestamp1 >='2010-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2015-01-01 00:05:00' group by day order by day desc,
```

and something like this

```
select id13 from timestamppsql where timestamp1 >='2010-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2011-01-01 00:05:00',  
select avg(id13)::numeric(10,2) from timestamppsql where timestamp1>='2015-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2015-01-01 10:30:00'
```

I will create an index :

```
create index project_index on timestamppsql(timestamp1,id13);
```

The question is which is the correct order for the index?`timestamp1` first or `id13`?
I know that the first index in order(from left to right) should be the one we use more,have the least duplicate values and the have most restrictive columns.Whats your opinion on that?

Comment: When in doubt, evaluate both versions.

Comment: @jarlh I agree with you!i just want to make a conversation in case i miss something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is the dominant clause for index creation.  You want the index to support filtering first.  So, you want `timestamp1` before id13` for these queries.

Note that in general Postgres visits the data pages even when an index is used, so `id13` may not be important to use in an index.  Postgres has improved optimization in more recent versions so in a table with no modifications, a covering index can be used.  All that is to say that `timestamp1` is really important as the first column in the index.  `id13` is much less important.

Comment: .Thank you!i appreciate your help!

Comment: .I have one more thing to ask you.I am using a table with about one million rows.I never delete something from my table or update it.I just import the data in the beginning and then i test queries.Should i worry about the statistics being up-to-date?

Comment: No, you need to worry about the table being vacuumed often enough so that you get fast index-only scans. Upgrade to v13 and tune `autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Does this mean that the advice that I give about covering indexes in *all* other databases will now work in Postgres?  Yay!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, since PostgreSQL 9.3, I think. The one catch is that you have to (auto-)`VACUUM` regularly, so that most blocks are marked "all-visible" in the *visibility map*, and a visibility check on the table is not needed for most rows.